# ORA-00604 when using ora_sql_txt

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger using the function [ora_sql_txt](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg14evt.htm)

I want to use a create table statement with length of around 2100 chars.

On one database, the trigger is working.
On the other database, I get the error:

> ORA-04088: Fehler bei der Ausführung von Trigger
> 'TESTUSER.TRIGGERNAME' ORA-00604: Fehler auf rekursiver SQL-Ebene 1
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler: Zeichenfolgenpuffer
> zu klein ORA-06512: in Zeile 42
> 04088. 00000 -  "error during execution of trigger '%s.%s'"
> *Cause:    A runtime error occurred during execution of a trigger.
> *Action:   Check the triggers which were involved in the operation.

I broke down the trigger to this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER SCHEMAUSER.TRIGGERNAME
    AFTER DDL ON SCHEMAUSER.SCHEMA
    DECLARE
         sql_text ora_name_list_t;
         n PLS_INTEGER;

    BEGIN
       IF (ora_sysevent ='CREATE' AND  ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE') THEN

          -- Get statement
          n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
          
       END IF;
    END;
```

Both databases are using the same oracle version 12.2.

Can somehow the values for PLS_INTEGER be changed? Does anybody have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: No idea why it's not working, but the error is 'string buffer too small', so it isn't going to be anything to do with `pls_integer`. Just to clarify, you still get the same error with the cut-down trigger; and it refers to the line with the assignment (which would be line 9 in the code you posted)? Or does it still refer to line 42? And you've changed the names, so are you sure the error actually refers to the trigger you think - and you don't have a different version of the trigger (e.g. under SYS as well as under TESTUSER)?

Answer (score 0):

I was logged in as another user that had the same trigger. Even though I changed another schema, the trigger for the schemauser I was logged in as was triggered. This caused the issue. Case closed.